# What causes Helm chart template to throw 'unexpected EOF'?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to add ingress to my nginx container.

The following ingress template gives me "parse error (<>/ingress.yaml:71: unexpected EOF)". I went through trying mark possible missing end statements, but even adding arbitrary end at the end of file didn't fix it. I am out of ideas as to what causes this EOF.

So the question is the general: What causes "unexpected EOF" in the file?

```yaml
{{- if .Values.web.ingress.enabled }}

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-proxy-ingress
  labels:
    tier: intelowl
    component: proxy
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- with .Values.labels }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }} # {{- with .Values.labels }}

{{- if .Values.web.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{- with .Values.web.ingress.annotations }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }} # {{- with .Values.web.ingress.annotations }}
{{- end }} # {{- if .Values.web.ingress.annotations }}

spec:

{{- if .Values.web.ingress.tls.enabled }}
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ .Values.web.ingress.host }}
      secretName: {{ .Values.web.ingress.tls.secretName }}
{{- end }} # {{- if .Values.web.ingress.tls.enabled }}

  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
{{- range .Values.web.ingress.precedingPaths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .serviceName }}
                port: 
                  number: {{ .servicePort }}
{{- end }} # {{- range .Values.web.ingress.precedingPaths }}

          - backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Release.Name }}-proxy
                port: 
                  number: {{ ternary 443 80 .Values.web.ingress.tls.enabled }}
{{- if .Values.web.ingress.path }}
            path: {{ .Values.web.ingress.path }}
{{- end }} # {{- if .Values.web.ingress.path }}

{{- range .Values.web.ingress.succeedingPaths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .serviceName }}
                port: 
                  number: {{ .servicePort }}
{{- end }} # {{- range .Values.web.ingress.succeedingPaths }}

{{- if .Values.web.ingress.host }}
      host: {{ .Values.web.ingress.host }}
{{- end }} # {{- if .Values.web.ingress.host }}

{{- end }} # {{- if .Values.web.ingress.enabled }}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your file is generally structured like so:

```
{{- if .Values.someCondition }}
...
{{- end }} # {{- if .Values.someCondition }}
```

However, the Go `text/template` engine runs before any YAML parsing happens.  There is *not* a comment in this example; there is an `if` statement, the matching `end`, and an unterminated `if`.

The `text/template` language has its own `{{/* comment */}}` syntax, and in principle you could use this

```
{{- if .Values.someCondition }}
...
{{- end }}{{/* if .Values.someCondition */}}
```

Beyond this, the file you show seems to have the right number of `{{ end }}`s.

I'd probably avoid this style myself.  Usually these condition blocks are fairly short; you could break the template into multiple `define` named templates if that helps.

```yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    tier: intelowl
    et: cetera
{{- include "more-labels" . | indent 4 }}
{{- include "ingress-annotations" . | indent 2 }}

{{- define "more-labels" -}}
{{ with .Values.labels }}{{ toYaml . }}{{ end }}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "ingress-annotations" -}}
{{- with .Values.web.ingress.annotations }}
annotations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 2 }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Especially for labels you might find that some of the values will be reused in all of your objects, and so including a template in the `_helpers.tpl` file to produce the common values will reduce some of the repetitiveness.